# Youtube embed ad revenue

Tags: youtube-api

Is there any program available to developers/website owners for a share in ad revenue for embedded videos, similar to how site owners can make money by showing google adwords?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have videos that have ads. I can control where the ads are shown, and also where the video is shown, but unless you come to a private agreement with the content producer for traffic driven to the video you wouldn't be able to receive any ad revenue.

Answer (score 1):

The ads are linked directly with the account holder of the video so I believe this would not be possible. You would be displaying that video's ads and therefor generating revenue for the owner of the video and never see a cent yourself.